# Accessing data from another class which reads values

Tags: java, class

Ok, so here is a problem: I have main class which generates a window and two buttons:

```
          ...
            public MainWindow()
            {           
          ...

                b_read.addActionListener(new ReadStudents());
                b_open_all.addActionListener(new OpenStudents());
          ...
```

In ReadStudents.java class I load data from a file with JFileChooser and print it on the screen. Sample of code thats load file:

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       ...
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(".");
       ...
        int rez = fc.showOpenDialog(fc);
        if (rez == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            ...
```

So now in my ReadStudents.java class variable "file" has my loaded information.
How do i pass this variable with containing information in it to a class that prints Students on the screen (second button OpenStudents.java) ?

Edit:1) I can not initialize an object of ReadStudents.java in OpenStudents.java class because in the new object variable "file" will be empty. Something is loaded to a "file" only when a button b_read is pressed.

Comment: There are tons of options. Is this a task for school? I suggest you ask your teacher/other students for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to implement the action listener on your MainWindow class and the call a method in the ReadStudents/OpenStudents that return the list of files.

For example:

```
/**
 * Main window class.
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
    mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    mainFrame.setSize(100, 100);
    final StudentReader student = new StudentReader();

    JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Make the call here. Take note!
            // Look at the return type!
            List<String> strings = student.fileNames();
            for (String s : strings) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    });
    mainFrame.add(button);
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

public class StudentReader {
    public List<String> fileNames() {
        // Do your magic here :)
        // Open a dialog. Get the files.
        // Return it as a list
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"Filename"});
    }
}
```

I Hope this helps!